# Subscript on Filtration of a Probability Space

Tags: stochastic-processes, filtrations

I have encountered a notation from Delia Coculescu's paper entitled "A Default System with Overspilling Contagion". It is this:

\begin{equation}
X_{t+}
\end{equation}
which is a filtration. What does the plus sign mean?

Comment: Perhaps $\cap_{s>t} X_s$.

Comment: Hi Kavi! Are you familiar with the paper?

Comment: No I am not. If each $X_t$ is a sigma filed then the only natural definition of $X_{t+}$ I can think  of is the one I have given.

Comment: Are you sure about the notation because usually $X$ is used to designate a process not a filtration. If this is the case, then $X_{t+}$ stands for the decreasing limit of the process $X_t$ at time $t$, Id Est $lim_{s\downarrow  t}X_s$.

Comment: @TheBridge The paper actually used script H. My apologies.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy thank you!

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Hi! I found a reference. You are right. Thank you 